Grafana: Create a graph for each row in Data table
I have the following data table from a redis data source:

which results in the following two graphs:

Currently the columns from, value_from and to, value_to are plotted as two graphs.
Is it possible to transform the data, s.t. each row is plotted as a separated graph, containing only two data points: one from value_from and value_to. The rows will always look like in the example, thus the resulting graphs, in this case 3, will always be linear functions.

I can't imagine how this would be done for table you showed, but if you were to convert it to format (rowid, timestamp, value), and treat rowid as metric name, I'd imagine Grafana plot exactly what you described.

I have a unique rowID, which is not shown in the screenshot above. How can I transform the data to (rowID, timestamp, value)?

This is more to the redis folks.
